# CAAnimation: Animation disabled automatically when app goes in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, caanimation

In my iPhone App,

I have put CAAnimation in my code...

When my app goes in background with animation on some button and come back button animation that was present I can not see

Why?

I have put methods to reinvoke the animation in appdidenter background...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application's execution is suspended when it goes to the background.
Although it seems that application remains active but that is not anymore, anything that draws to the view will be halted when application moves to the background state.
refer following ios developer link for detailed information- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html